# Does Hashtag in the URL affect SEO rankings for as Angular JS web application

Tags: seo, google-ranking, angular.js

I am using Angular JS to develop my web application. My current URL will be like this: `localhost:8080/#!/home`.

I can remove hash tag from the url and make it: `localhost:8080/home` but does that help me in getting good SEO ranking in Google?

If adding the hashtag doesn't affect my SEO rankings (even not that much), I can use this.

Note: All my page URLs will be added only after `#!`

Comment: Google's John Mueller has answered this question: https://www.seroundtable.com/google-no-url-fragments-23449.html

Comment: Google deprecated the "hash bang" AJAX crawling in October 2015: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification    There is now no reason to use `#!` in your URLs.

Answer (score 2):

Google just don't understand what the meaning of `/#!/` or any other thing like `/10787/` in this question URL, but [they can crawl the hashbang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiAF9VdvRPw) `/#!/` URL just like other URL's.

I suggest to go for clean URL's, if it take only few hours to setup, it will impress your visitors as well. The keyword in [URL affect very very small in ranking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRzMhlFZz9I), but the position of keyword like after `/#!/` or `/10787/` or [after 3 sub directory does not make much difference.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_A1iRY6XTM)

Comment: Google has [deprecated their AJAX crawling scheme](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html), so now I believe Google does not crawl hash/hashbang URLs.